# How to using local file when run dsl.ContainerOp in kubeflow-pipeline

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines

As I known when we using dsl.ContainerOp in kubeflow pipeline with sdk

```
ContainerOp(
    name=step_name,
    image='katib/mxnet-mnist-example',
    command=['python', '/mxnet/example/image-classification/train_mnist.py'],
    arguments=[
      '--batch-size', '64',
      '--lr', learning_rate,
      '--num-layers', num_layers,
      '--optimizer', optimizer
    ])
```

train_mnist.py will existed in image katib/mxnet-mnist-example with dir /mxnet/example/image-classification

However, due to I wanna modify many times training file like **train_mnist.py** i don't want re-build image and coppy train_mnist.py from local to image dir.

Currently i using mount the source code from s3 and nfs to container, but i don't want using this method because i test to using CI for this problem.
Do you know another approach to pass training file that i want to modify with not re-build image, re-build image and push to hub take many times with my image using pytorch, tensorflow or mxnet,...

Thank everyone!

Currently i using mount the source code from s3 and nfs to container, but i don't want using this method because i test to using CI for this problem.